# i want a little sound like a bell

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i just want a little sound . . .
printf("\a") doesnt works

thkx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90196/i-want-a-little-sound-like-a-bell/) by [Darkcarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/7681/darkcarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [sound_play](http://wiki.ros.org/sound_play) package.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2